# Understanding a relationship between sample and population mean for sample of iids

Tags: normal-distribution, sufficient-statistics

I have been reading "Applied Statistical Inference" by Held and Bove. In example 2.21 they came upon this expression while trying to show a statistic is sufficient:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n(x_i - \mu)^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^n(x_i - \bar{x})^2 + n(\bar{x} - \mu)^2$$

I am having a hard time understanding where this expression comes from. I would be very grateful if someone could shed light into the matter.

Comment: It's a simple result of expanding out the left hand side of the equation and adding zero ($\overline{x} - \overline{x}$). The only moderately interesting consequence is that the sum of squared differences from the sample mean will always be smaller than the sum of squared differences from the population mean. In fact, some simple calculus shows that $\overline{x}$ minimizes the function $$g(c) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - c)^2$$

Comment: Ah. I understand now. I appreciate it!

Comment: So far I'm the only one who's up-voted this question or Michael Chernick's answer.

Comment: I'd love to give Michael Chernick some more props, but my rep is below 15 so I am not able to do so.

Answer (score 3):

[All you have to do is take $(X_i - \mu)^2$ and add and subtract $\overline{x}$ inside because

$(X_i - \overline{x} + \overline{x} -\mu)^2$

is the same as doing this algebra

$(X_i - \overline{x})^2 + (\overline{x} - \mu)^2 + 2 (X_i - \overline{x}) (\overline{x} - \mu)$. After summation you get $\sum_i (X_i -\overline{x})^2  + n (\overline{x}-\mu)^2$ Note that $(\overline{x} - \mu)^2$ is independent of i. So adding it n times give the n in front of it .

Now $\sum_i [ 2 (X_i - \overline{x}) (\overline{x} - \mu)^2] = 2 (\overline{x} - \mu)^2 \sum_i[ (X_i - \overline{x}) ]$ since we can take the constant

terms out of the summation.

Now notice that $\sum_i [(X_i - \overline{x} )] = 0$ since $\sum_i X_i = n \overline{x}$ cancels out - $\sum_i \overline{x} = - n \overline{x}$

Comment: If someone who knows how to use MathJax can edit my equations I would appreciate it.

Comment: Review my edit. I didn't knock myself out but just did a few search and replaces. It's more readable now.

Comment: Thank you that was fine I added to the edits correcting spelling.  You did fine gammer.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
& \sum_{i = 1}^n(x_i - \mu)^2 \\[10pt] = {} & \sum_{i=1}^n \Big( (x_i-\bar x)+(\bar x - \mu) \Big)^2 \\[10pt]
= {} & \sum_{i=1}^n \Big( (x_i-\bar x)^2 + 2(x_i-\bar x)(\bar x - \mu) + (\bar x - \mu)^2 \Big) \\[10pt]
= {} & \left( \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2}_A \right) + \left( \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n 2(x_i -\bar x)(\bar x - \mu)}_B \right) + \left( \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n (\bar x - \mu)^2}_C \right)
\end{align}

In the sum labeled $B$, the factor $2(\bar x - \mu)$ does not change as $i$ goes from $1$ to $n$; therefore it can be pulled out, yielding
$$
2(\bar x - \mu) \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x).
$$
This sum is $0$, so the term labeled $B$ vanishes.

In the sum labeled $C$, the term $(\bar x - \mu)^2$ does not change as $i$ goes from $1$ to $n$, so it can be pulled out, yielding
$$
(\bar x - \mu)^2 \sum_{i=1}^n 1.
$$
This is $n(\bar x - \mu)^2.$

Comment: Notwithstanding the prettier typesetting, this is almost an exact duplicate of the previously posted answer.

Comment: Great minds think alike. (But some do prettier typesetting.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy I agree with gammer that our two answers are essentially the same.  Normally I would suggest that you delete your answer.  But in this case you express in symbols some things that I said in words.  The symbols may make yours a little clearer to the mathematically inclined. I do think the OP understood based on his comment both of our presentations.

Comment: Actually I've posted essentially this answer several times on math(dot)stackexchange(dot)com.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, are you bragging about knowingly answering duplicate questions?

Comment: @not_bonferroni : They weren't all identical but there was some overlap.

Comment: @not_bonferroni In my case I felt that this was a standard trick and if I searched hard enough I might find it as a duplicate, part of another post or by referring to some basic statistics book.  I felt that the OP would appreciate learning a simple trick. So I gave it to him.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, No need to explain. I understand that people rarely have the need/desire to search for duplicates in advance. A large majority of answers on this site seem to be duplicates at this point. The only exceptions are particularly complicated questions. I was just surprised at what seemed to be someone saying they intentionally answer confirmed duplicates.

Comment: @not_bonferroni : "Particularly complicated" isn't the only way to be unusual. $\qquad$